# cmake: Selecting a generator within CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I would like to **force CMake** to use the "Unix Makefiles" **generator** from within CMakeLists.txt.

**This is the command I use now.**

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .
```

**I would like it to be this.**

```
cmake .
```

When running on windows with VC installed and a custom tool-chain.

I would expect to be-able to set the generator in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

**Maybe something like this.**

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
```

Answer (score 34):

Here is what worked for me - create a file called **PreLoad.cmake** in your project dir containing this:

`set (CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)`

Comment: It looks like the `Preload.cmake` behavior was not documented in the "official" cmake documentation; see [ticket 17231](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17231) -- but good to know!

Comment: Is there a better way as of 2020 / cmake 3.17? This does not seem to work in the same way -GNinja does

Answer (score 19):

It seems to me that the variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` is set too late if set in the `CMakeLists.txt`.  If you use (even at the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt`)

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja")
message("generator is set to ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")
```

you can see in the output something like

```
% cmake ../source
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
...
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
generator is set to Ninja
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build
```

So the variable is only set at the very end of the generation procedure.  If you use something like

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

in `CMakeLists.txt`, then in the very first run of `cmake ../source` (without `-G`) the *default* generator is used.  The variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` is stored in the cache, though.  So if you rerun `cmake ../source` afterwards, it will use the generator as specified in the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable in the cache.

This is surely not the most elegant solution, though ;-)  Maybe use a batch file that will actually execute the `cmake -G generator` for the user...

Comment: I wish they would let the user set all configuration in `CMakeLists.txt`. What's the point if you need a `.bat` over it?

Comment: Looks like [Ivan's answer](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17231) does something very close to this -- the variable is configured in a cmake config file that is sourced before the actual `CMakeLists.txt` is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

This is not what I get, when I run the same command, cmake will look for a gcc compiler / make utility. If the PATH is not set up correctly it will fail with something like:

```
D:\Development\build>cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..\source
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.
  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:D:/Development/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:D:/Development/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

when gcc / mingw is in the path then everything works fine. So could you provide more information as to your PATH variable or CMAKE version?

Comment: Because I am using a custom tool-chain, and I have VC++ installed, I can't rely on CMake selecting a generator. I also don't what to specify one on the command line so that it is easy for the user to clone and build the project.

Comment: Ok ... sorry I misunderstood your question. In that case I would recommend placing a CMakeCache.txt into the directory, which is mostly empty but for the CMAKE_GENERATOR variable. Or you could have that cache file in your source repository and pass it along using the -C cmake option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the generator at the Generate stage so it is written into the cache.
You only need to run this command once for the first configuration

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Ninja

This will configure Ninja as the default generator.

Later you can simply run

> cmake ..

And it would use the Ninja generator as default

You can read more about it under [Running CMake from the command line](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/)

> When running cmake from the command line, it is possible to specify command line options to cmake that will set values in the cache. This is done with a -DVARIABLE:TYPE=VALUE syntax on the command line. This is useful for non-interactive nightly test builds.

Answer (score 1):

CMake 3.19 introduces a new feature - presets. So, to select proper generator automatically, you can specify it name in `CMakePresets.json`.

Full description for these files available here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html