# How to write CMakeLists.txt with NOT using 'MSBuild.exe' on windows?

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I'm trying to write the `CMakeLists.txt` for building a **custom targets only** project.

That is, it's not for the usual C/C++ project; all build recipes are provided using `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND()` and `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET()`. The reason why I'm using CMake is to manage dependencies between build target stuffs and utilize the advantages of incremental build.

The problem is, when I execute `cmake CMakeLists.txt` on Windows cmd.exe, it tries to find Windows SDK or MSBuild.exe -- which are never needed for building targets in the project.

```
cmd.exe> cmake CMakeLists.txt
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild Command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Cannot find file

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
```

The header of the `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 3.0 )
set ( CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefile" )
set ( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE true )

# Project name
project ( "awesome-project" NONE )  # <language>=NONE for skipping compiler check

...
```

As I mentioned above, all recipes of the build targets are provided in the `CMakeLists.txt`; neither Windows SDK nor Visual Studio is required.

I think there is some CMake directives for skipping the invocation of MSBuild, but I could not find it. How can I write the `CMakeLists.txt` in this case?

Comment: CMake uses `MSBuild.exe` not for the *compiling*, but for **building** the project - it will detect changes in dependent files and run corresponded commands you use in `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`. The thing is that CMake is only a **configuration** tool, not a *build* one. The tool used for build is choosen according to the [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), which is among a few things you cannot set inside `CMakeLists.txt`. Build tool `MSBuild.exe` corresponds to Visual Studio generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819405/3987854) suggests, setting the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable in the CMake file has no effect when running CMake *for the first time*. CMake will use the default generator on the first attempt, if no generator is provided via the command line or via environment variable. So try adding the command line [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) `-G` to specify the generator like this:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .
```

Then, on subsequent CMake runs, the generator setting will be cached and you no longer need to provide the `-G` generator option.

As a side note, you can simply provide the *path* to your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file. So if it's in the current directory, you can just use `.` for the path.

Comment: I did not know that this problem was related to generator option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty explicit `The value of this variable should never be modified by project code. A generator may be selected via the cmake(1) -G option, interactively in cmake-gui(1), or via the CMAKE_GENERATOR environment variable.`

You can always make a CMake script that runs CMake with the proper options to create the project.

You may want to keep watch on `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` because `This variable is a cache entry initialized (to FALSE) by the project() command.`  I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work as shown in your script.  Instead You'd probably have to add a -D option on the command line to set it. https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/make-building-with-cmake-verbose