# Creating a clang tool that can run on existing makefile projects in a Windows Evironment?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, clang, llvm

I want to write a clang tool that can run on C++ projects that I have that already exist which use Makefiles to build. The problem is, it seems as though any project that is going to be put through a clang AST *must* be built using cmake so that it can get a compile_commands.json file. Is there a way to do this for projects that don't use cmake? Or is there a way to build Makefile projects with cmake?

Comment: Why don't you use GNU Make for Windows?

Comment: `Or is there a way to build Makefile projects with cmake?` Mhm, `cmake` is used to create `Makefiles` for your project?! See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395169/using-cmake-to-generate-visual-studio-c-project-files how to do it with Visual Studio...

Comment: Some searching brought up [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear), but that looks to be unix only.

Comment: These projects run on both linux and windows, so I have no problem on the linux side of things because as David Brown mentioned, bear solves my problem there

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use this script with cygwin:

https://github.com/woboq/woboq_codebrowser/blob/master/scripts/fake_compiler.sh

Comment: Nice. That seems to be simplier than bear. Do you think it is better if you know what compiler is invoked anyway?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about bear. I have the luxury of using CMake all the time :).