# adding "reference" point to a static-library project : still need to include directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have read Microsoft's tutorial ["Creating and Using a Static Library (C++)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627(v=vs.90).aspx), and successfully follow it.

Here is the dummy project :-

- `B` : name of a static library project
- `C` : name of a project that uses `B`

Here is what Microsoft guides :-

1. click "Add references" in `C`, then click `B`  (easy)
2. add "Additional Include Directories" of `C` to point to `B`'s code folder

Why do I have to do the second (redundant) step?
It causes some maintainability issue & tedious, especially if I have a lot of projects.

Is it what experts do?
I believed just the 1st step should be enough, but after testing it doesn't.

**Question:**

- Are there any better workflow?      What is it?
- If no, how to maintain the include directory (if I move `B`'s folder around)?

After searching SO, I come to believe that there are no better way and I have to maintain it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 ("Add references") is for the linker, Step 2 ("Additional Include Directories") is for the compiler.

It's true that the IDE could be smart enough to operate step 2 automatically. However, you may not add the whole `B`'s code folder to be seen by `C`. Most likely you meant to only point to a folder listing `B` interfaces (public header files), `C` should not see `B` private/internal headers nor `B` source code: it's surely too difficult for the IDE to figure out where it is exactly, that's why the user should do it manually.

For your last questions: what "experts" do is that they commonly don't edit/maintain IDE files by hand, they have them be generated by a tool, like [CMake](https://cmake.org/). Then, when structure changes, they just re-generate the project (sln/vcproj) files (run CMake again).

Comment: Do you have more must-read about workflow of cMake+VS in your mind? (besides the link)  Thank.

Comment: @javaLover: CMake is a great tool, once it's in place, it will help you managing all your libraries/programs/tests compilation steps smartly.

Comment: I believe so (heard a lot of good rumor around it).  How should I learn it?  Is googling "visual studio cmake tutorial" sound OK?

Comment: @javaLover: Check https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395169/using-cmake-to-generate-visual-studio-c-project-files