# Cloning a GitHub repo to create a buildable Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-c++, clone

I know how to use Team Explorer to clone a repo from GitHub but my problem is that when I do this, I can't build and debug the resulting code (I'm using C++ and I have the C/C++ add-on for VS) the way I can if I create a project from scratch in VS (by hitting the green "play" button). This seems to be because I'm missing some of the many extra VS-specific files that are created when you I create a VS project from scratch. Can anyone help me out please?

I've searched SO and Youtube for answers but all that ever seems to be covered is clicking the cloning in Team Explorer - nobody seems to mention building and debugging once you have cloned.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I don't get a build option so unfortunately I can't get as far as an error.

Answer (score 0):

A source repo is generally two things : the actual sources and their build system. You need to figure out what is the build system of the repo you're cloning (usually: [GNUMake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/), [autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html), VS project, etc.) and use it.

Some build systems (like CMake) can [generate project files for various IDE like microsoft studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395169/5470596).