# How to add a CMAKE generator to the Linux version of CMAKE?

Tags: linux, windows, cmake

I am on a Windows machine running the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  When I installed the CLI version of CMAKE on the WSL it did not come with any generators for visual studio (i.e. `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64`).

How do I add these to the Linux version of CMAKE?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the Windows version of CMake for Visual Studio?

Comment: If your end goal is compiling software for Windows using the Linux subsystem, you need to set your project up for cross compiling: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I just wanted to run the `cmake` command from the command line in the WSL because I like it better than the command line for Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No can do. As per [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html):

> CMake Generators are platform-specific so each may be available only on certain platforms. The cmake(1) command-line tool --help output lists available generators on the current platform.

Even if you built CMake yourself, you wouldn't be able to compile the Visual Studio generators because [they rely on the Windows API](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/5a283b79e5fe1739142cc513a9a701855849b2f8/Source/cmGlobalVisualStudioGenerator.cxx#L11).

Comment: There is no way to harness Visual Studio generators through WSL?